# Calculate this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$, I want to show that
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow+\infty}\left(a^n+b^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\max(a,b).$$
My aim is to obtain the following formula: If $a_k\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$ for all $k$, then
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow+\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^da_k^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\max_{k}a_k.$$
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It's not true, so it will be hard to prove.

Comment: $\lim_{n\longrightarrow+\infty}\left(a^n+b^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\color{red}{\max(a,b)}$ ?

Comment: Assume $a,b\geq 0$, @DonaldSplutterwit is correct.

Comment: If we assume that $a,b≥0$, could you please help me with advice or helping hints in order to prove it? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A = \max(a,b)$, where $a,b \ge 0$.

Then for all $n$: $A^n \le (a^n+b^n) \le 2A^n$,so

$$(A^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \le (a^n + b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \le (2A^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

The left is just a fancy way to write $A$.
The right hand side is $(2)^{\frac{1}{n}}(A^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}= A(2)^{\frac{1}{n}} \to A$ as well, as $n \to \infty$. So standard theorems imply that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a^n+b^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = A = \max(a,b)$$

Comment: More generally if $a_k\geq0$ for all $k$, then
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow+\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^da_k^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\max_{k}a_k??$$

Comment: @Phdstudent yes, a variant of this argument works, with $d$ instead of 2 as well.

Comment: Works for any $d$ such that $d^{1/n} \to 1$. In particular for finite $d$ and $d=n$.